# NestJS config validate function

Tags: webpack, nestjs-config

I use in the NestJS config module a custom validate function.

When I run my app in the development mode there are any problems, bu in the production mode if my validate function throws an exception I see a listing of my code after webpack and just after it is shown an error text.
How to avoid of printig a code listing?

```
[cut]
enableVersioning({defaultVersion:"1",type:n.VersioningType.URI}),e.useLogger(e.get(c.PinoLogger));const p=(new s.DocumentBuilder).setTitle("Payment System").setDescription("It helps make paymets easely").setVersion("1.0").build(),y=s.SwaggerModule.createDocument(e,p);s.SwaggerModule.setup(a,e,y),e.enableShutdownHooks();const f=e.get(c.AppConfigService).get("PORT");await e.listen(f),n.Logger.log(`\ud83d\ude80 Application is running on: http://${r.hostname()}:${f}/${a}`)}()})();var __webpack_export_target__=exports;for(var i in __webpack_exports__)__webpack_export_target__[i]=__webpack_exports__[i];__webpack_exports__.__esModule&&Object.defineProperty(__webpack_export_target__,"__esModule",{value:!0})})();
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

Error: Validation errors
    at a.validate (/Users/vic/Dev/services/dist/apps/payments/main.js:1:35188)
    at ConfigModule.forRoot (/Users/vic/Dev/services/node_modules/@nestjs/config/dist/config.module.js:70:45)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (/Users/vic/Dev/services/dist/apps/payments/main.js:1:957)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/vic/Dev/services/dist/apps/payments/main.js:1:728536)
    at /Users/vic/Dev/services/dist/apps/payments/main.js:1:728881
    at /Users/vic/Dev/services/dist/apps/payments/main.js:1:729636
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vic/Dev/services/dist/apps/payments/main.js:1:729868)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
```